# How to properly validate data from $_GET or $_REQUEST using WordPress functions?

Tags: plugin-development, security, validation, sanitization

I am working on a plugin that requires on-the-fly manipulation of content output. This is solely dependent on the current `$_GET` variable or `$_REQUEST` variable.

Depending on what the variable is set to, it will call a certain class method to handle the user's request and display the proper content.

I am fully aware of the [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) page on the WordPress Codex, however, I am unsure of what the best approach is for my scenario, or any scenario of sanitizing `$_GET` variables or `$_REQUEST` variables for that matter.

How can I sanitize using WordPress functions for `$_GET` variable or `$_REQUEST` variable for a string which will be matched to call a specific class method?

**Could this be exploited or fail given the following code?:**

```
public function display_admin_page(){
    if(is_admin() && isset($_GET['page'])){
        global $content;
        $page = sanitize_title($_GET['page']);
        $method_name = 'page_'.str_replace('-', '_', $page);
        if(method_exists('content', $method_name)){
            // Display requested page from content class
            $thePage = $content->$method_name();
        } else{
            $thePage = $content->error(404);    
        }
        echo $thePage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### WordPress doesn't provide any specific data validation functions for SUPERGLOBALS.

#### I use the PHP [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function then escape it as I would any untrusted variable.

```
$url = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'some_query_string', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL );

echo '<a href="'. esc_url( $url ). '">Click Me</a>';
```

The PHP filter input accepts:

- [Validate filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)
- [Sanitize filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
- [Other filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php)
- [Additional Filter flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php)

Comment: @Chris_0, how about `$_GET` requests? For example, `filter_var( $_GET[ $item['name'] ], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS )`  Should this be implemented in a different way?

Answer (score 3):

To your specific example:

You sanitized the $_GET data appropriately (thought I would use `sanitize_key` instead of `sanitize_title` -- can't say there's much of a difference, but `sanitize_title` is intended for use in URLs).

The `method_exists` function will return true for private and protected methods, so if a user tries to call a private or protected method, it'll fail without going to the 404. (Unless the `display_admin_page` method is in the same class.)

That brings us to the main potential exploit: that absolutely anyone can force any public method in your class to run.  If possible, it's always better to specifically whitelist what can be accepted.  That way you could validate with something like:

```
if ( !in_array( $_GET['page'], array( 'accepted_method', 'another_accepted_method' ) ) )
     $content->error(404);
```

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate more on the potential exploit theory?

Comment: Sure, I mean it's just something you have to think through. Every public method in your class can be forced to run by anyone at any time. That's not *automatically* an exploit, but it's a consideration. Is there a method in your class that deletes from your database? Is there a method that echoes your users' passwords? Will you ever add other methods you need to worry about? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET)` on any GET request. It's a very powerful PHP feature.

You can then use `str_replace()` to replace any unwanted characters.

**UPDATE 2023:**

`esc_sql()` is the perfect solution.

Comment: Isn't the WordPress function `esc_sql()` a better choice?

Comment: @gillespieza of course it is, but in 2012 that function is better. It's an 11 year-old answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Sanitizing `$_GET` is pretty much context specific. Depends on what value you want and how you want it to be validated.

There is no one-sized fits all answer to this question. It is very context specific. For example, you could write a function that stripped all tags and slashes from input, that's very safe, but what if you wanted a p tag to be saved? No harm there. The wp_kses() family is an interesting study, but is not a great solution, as it takes into account context, user level and more. For example, as an admin user you can save JavaScript in post title and post content, but as a lower role, you can not.

If it's value is a known quantity, you can also check if `in_array( $array_valid_strings )` and be extra sure about those.

That said, there are different degrees of sanitization, so it's important to keep your end goal in mind. I would consult this list and find the function or combination of functions that fits your needs. It's specifically the sanitize_ functions that should be used here, not esc_. Sanitization and escaping continue to be confused...

In my case I am going to use [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) because it sanitizes a string from user input or from the database.

- Checks for invalid UTF-8,
- Converts single < characters to entities
- Strips all tags
- Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
- Strips octets

Good luck :).

P.S. This answer quotes three different developer's perspectives (Josh, Michal, Kevin).